# VisualStateManager in MahApps.Metro Window

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

does anyone know how to get the visual state manager running in the following code? Even Blend is not helping at all. If I define Visual State Groups and Visual States nothing works or changes.

```
<controls:MetroWindow
...
<controls:MetroWindow.Content>
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>                
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ProgressVisualStateGroup">
                <VisualState x:Name="NeutralVisualState">
                    ...
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="InProgressVisualState">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="progressStatusBarItem" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="errorStatusBarItem" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="synchronizeIncidentsButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsEnabled)">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False"/>
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="ErrorVisualState">
                   ...
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Fluent:Ribbon x:Name="ribbonControl" Grid.Row="0">
        ...
        </Fluent:Ribbon>
        <controls:SplitView  Grid.Row="1"
        ...
        </controls:SplitView>
        <Fluent:StatusBar Grid.Row="2">
        ...
        </Fluent:StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</controls:MetroWindow.Content>
```

Comment: How do you trigger these visual states?

Comment: The "InProgressVisualState" should be triggered by either button with "GotoStateAction", which doesn't work. Even when I define the states in Blend and switch manually between them - nothing changes... Neutral and Error will be triggered by a property later. I am convinced, it is not working because of that MahApps template construction.